# Similar, but different curve to critically damped harmonic oscillator solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for a curve with similar attributes to a critically damped harmonic oscillator, but is slightly different. As a reminder, the 
"classical" damped harmonic oscillator equation is:

$$x(t) = m\ddot{x}+b\dot{x}+k x$$

and it is critically damped when $b^2=4mk$.

The attributes of the solution to this equation that I want to keep are:

1. Quickness in returning to equilibrium
2. Not oscillating

It is difficult to describe in words what I am looking for to be different, so an example will demonstrate what I am looking for best:

Consider the following critically damped oscillator,

$$x(t) = \ddot{x}+4\dot{x}+4 x$$

With initial conditions of

$$
x(0) = -5\\
\dot{x}(0) = 50
$$

Here is a plot of the solution curve:

[image]

The following image highlights the fact that the area of the curve to the left of the maximum is much smaller than the area to the right of the maximum.

[image]

I am looking for a curve where the areas to the left and right are more equal. I would also prefer a more aggressive approach to equilibrium. The following image demonstrates the kind of curve I am looking for:

[image]

From my evaluation of the classical damped harmonic oscillator equation, it is not possible to generate curves with this shape. I am thinking that it may be more fruitful to consider a different sort of dampening factor (the $b\dot{x}$ piece of the equation).

My question is: do you know of something like a classical critically damped harmonic oscillator that would generate the kind of curve I am looking for? Rather than guessing, I thought that somebody here may have an intuition of oscillators and may be able to guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you can generate the desired curve with any damped oscillator with a strong enough spring force (large values of $k$).

(I may edit this answer with some graphs once I have them)